# How to obtain channel message "from" when message was sent by email?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, message, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using graph API to get `chatMessage`s from a microsoft teams channel by querying
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/channels/19:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY@thread.tacv2/messages`

This is working great for the most part, however there is a problem when a message was sent to the channel using the channel's email address.

For such a message, the teams client shows the sender's email address together with am email icon [like this (can not yet embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz5TI.png).

But when fetching the message from the graph API, the `from` field is `null`.
For example:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.chatMessage",
    "replyToId": null,
    "etag": "1599449691180",
    "messageType": "message",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-09-07T03:34:51.18Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "subject": "テスト件名",
    "summary": null,
    "chatId": null,
    "importance": "normal",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "webUrl": "(retracted)",
    "from": null,
    "policyViolation": null,
    "id": "1599449691180",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "テストメール<br>\n<br>"
    },
    "channelIdentity": {
        "teamId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "channelId": "19:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY@thread.tacv2"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "mentions": [],
    "reactions": []
}
```

**Is there any way to obtain the sender's email address like displayed in the teams client?**
Or the fact that this was submitted by email from some external source?

**Edit/Clarification:**
It seems, that this only happens, when the email is not from an O365 account or if the sender is not member of the team.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue. I was able to get the 'from' property as shown below.
*****************************************************************
"from": {
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "conversation": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": "1ab4e76f-5f52-44b8-8a72-7d03c05e6ff4",
                    "displayName": "Shiva Keshav Varma",
                    "userIdentityType": "aadUser"
                }
            }
*****************************************************************

Comment: You will receive the from details when user is member of the team, you will receive null when user is not member of the team.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Is there any reason for this? The teams client shows the email address just fine.

Comment: There is an bug on this issue giving from details as null when user is not a member of that team. We are tracking it internally, We don't have ETA to share when it will be available.